# Unable to determine structure as arff

Tags: weka, arff

I am trying to upload an arff file on weka but it is creating this problem:

> Unable to determine structure as arff (Reason:
>   java.io.IOException:}expected at end of enumeration,read Token[EOL],
>   line 4)

```
@RELATION data1

@ATTRIBUTE attribute_0 {"T,"N,"A,"C,"V}
@ATTRIBUTE attribute_1 REAL
@ATTRIBUTE attribute_2 {""VRoot"",""0""",""1""",""Hide1"",1,10001",1",10002",10003",10004",10005",10006",10007",10008",10009",10010",10011",10012",10013",10014",10015",10016",10017",10018",10019",10020",10021",10022",10023",10024",10025",10026",10027",100
```

Comment: There is no way we can help you without seeing the ARFF file. Since the error seems to be in line 4, can you add the first five lines to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ARFF Format Documentation](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/arff.html), `REAL` is not a valid attribute type.

Try `NUMERIC`.

Also be careful with quotes. The parser may assume that `"` is used to quote strings, and your quotes do not match.